# Javascript: setting an object's properties when the object is within a method?

Tags: javascript

I have an function that contains an object. Some of the object's properties are defined dynamically, and the entire object is returned to the parent function.

```
var myClass = {
    "my method": function(x) {
        var obj = {
            "one": {
                "stuff: "apples",
                "more stuff": "blah,
            },
            "two": {
                "stuff": "stuff",
                "blah": "blah blah"
            },
            "three": {
                "dynamic": x
            }
        };
        return obj;
    }
 }
```

You can access the properties of the method like this...

```
myClass['my method']()['one']['stuff'] //apples
```

But how can I set properties inside `obj`?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myClass['my method']()['one']['stuff'] = i; //undefined
    myClass['my method']['three']['dynamic'] = i //undefined
    myClass['my method'](i)['three']['dynamic'] // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
}
```

If the `obj` object were not inside a function it would be easy but there's clearly some syntax I'm missing.

Comment: ??? The first line of code (in the loop) you've got is exactly how you'd do it.  What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: Your missing `"` after stuff and blah. It's just typos [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/x04dp435/1/). Make sure you check you console for errors

Comment: Perhaps something you don't understand is that every time you call `myClass['my method']()` a brand new object is returned that will not contain any changes made to earlier objects.

Comment: So if the object is in a method, every time the method is called a new object is being instantiated? If so that's the problem I'm having.